# Как сделать выполнение команд только при упоминании бота в сообщении?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Приложение: Discord
Библиотека: Discord.py
Пример:
Должно работать: @бот команда
Недолжно работать: команда

Answer (score 0):

Идея, если честно, так себе, но если прям очень надо, то это можно сделать через on_message, так как упоминание в строковой интерпретации это `<@id участника, которого упоминают>`:

```
async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message) -> None:
    if message.content.startswith(f"<@{bot_id}>"):
        command = message.content.split()[1]
        args = message.content.split()[1:]
        print(command)
    else:
        print("Not a command")
```